# Pass String from activity to library class

Tags: java, android, openframeworks

I trying to pass a string from mainActivity to the activity of a 
   library i been trying using intent but is not recognizing this function has someone done this before?

I get this error:[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hweq0.png)

Comment: The class is not an Activity

Comment: Okay, thanks. I use mostly c++ not very experience in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create the `OFAndroid` class like this

```
public class OFAndroid {

 private String text ;
 public OFAndroid(String text) { 
  this.text = text ; 
 } 


 public void useText() {
   Log.e("TAG" , this.text);
 }
}
```

Inside your `MainActivity` instantiate `OFAndroid`:

```
OFAndroid of = new OFAndroid("some string");
```

now you can use the passed String

```
of.useText();
```

Answer (score 0):

getIntent is a method that is not available in your OFAndroid Class. If you want to access the Intent that was passes to an Activity you should call It from inside an Activity's Class.

Comment: Thanks, and how can i access the string from the class?

Comment: If you are instantiating It from inside the activity, you have to get the String inside the activity and then pass it's value to your Class. You can add a String field in your Class and create a setString(String) method on It, and then in the method you assign the String to the variable

Comment: Thanks a lot! how do i do this part  setString(String) method on It? sorry not have much experience in java.